# C# Powershell Commandlet to work with two parameters, but at most one can be specified

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, commandlet

I am implementing a Powershell commandlet in C#. The commandlet can be passed two parameters. Both are marked as optional (because I don't know in advance whether the user will issue `Get-MsiInstalled -Product "0449F3E3-2337-45EF-BE77-60F4B9CD8822"` Or `Get-MsiInstalled -MsiFile "C:filePath\file.msi"`.

Moreover, if the user is giving nothing and issueing Get-MsiInstalled an exception will be thrown (Either MSI or Product parameter must be specified).

Right now the implementation can't expect at most one parameter. Instead the user can provide both parameters and that is an invalid call.

```
public class GetAHPIsMsiInstalled : Cmdlet
{      
    [Parameter(Mandatory = false, ValueFromPipeline = true,
        HelpMessage = "Product Guid to search Installable Package.", Position = 1)]
    [UsedImplicitly]
    public string Product { get; set; }

    [Parameter(Mandatory = false, ValueFromPipeline = true, HelpMessage = "Installable Package to search.",
        Position = 1)]
    [UsedImplicitly]
    public string MsiFile { get; set; }

    protected override void BeginProcessing()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Product) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(MsiFile))
            ThrowTerminatingError(new ErrorRecord(new
                    ParameterBindingException("At most one parameter must be provided"))

        base.BeginProcessing();
        ................................
     }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [ParameterSets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/cmdlet/cmdlet-parameter-sets).  These allow you to specify mutually-exclusive sets of parameters.  This is how, for example, `Get-Process` can be called with `-Name` or `-Id`, but not both.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Please write down your answer at Answer section, and I will mark it as "Answer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ParameterSets are the way to specify mutually-exclusive sets of parameters.

This is how, for example, `Get-Process` can be called with `-Name` or `-Id`, but not both:

```
Get-Process [[-Name] <String[]>] [-ComputerName <String[]>] [-FileVersionInfo] [-Module] [<CommonParameters>]

Get-Process [-ComputerName <String[]>] [-FileVersionInfo] -Id <Int32[]> [-Module] [<CommonParameters>]

Get-Process [-ComputerName <String[]>] [-FileVersionInfo] -InputObject <Process[]> [-Module] [<CommonParameters>]

Get-Process -Id <Int32[]> -IncludeUserName [<CommonParameters>]

Get-Process [[-Name] <String[]>] -IncludeUserName [<CommonParameters>]

Get-Process -IncludeUserName -InputObject <Process[]> [<CommonParameters>]
```

You can specify them in [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/cmdlet/cmdlet-parameter-sets) or 
directly in [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-6#parametersetname-argument)